# In need of an example: A countable product of countable sets is not necessarily countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that finite cartesian product of countable sets is countable and I also know how to prove it but I'm in need of an example for the following:

> A countable product of countable sets is not necessarily countable

I've had a hard time trying to figure out an example. Is anyone out there with an example? Thanks for your time and efforts!

Comment: Intuitive hint.  If you list the digits the decimal expansion of a real number that will give you a countable sequence.  And that can be thought of as a single element of a countable Cartesian product of copies of $\mathbb Z_{10} $.  So the set of real numbers is such a countable product.

Comment: ...i.e.  $[0, 1] = \mathbb Z_{10}^{\infty} $ and $\mathbb \R=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb  Z_{10}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Why I'm I been downvoted and why is the question been brought to a close? I think I should be encouraged! This is a private study (with no Teacher or Instructor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, a countable product of countable sets (or a countable product of finite sets) is *hardly ever* countable, except in trivial cases. For the simplest example, consider the set
$$S=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\{0,1\}.$$
$S$ is just the set of all infinite sequences of zeros and ones. A simple application of Cantor's diagonal argument shows that $S$ is uncountable. 
Each element of $S$ is a function $f:\mathbb N\to
\{0,1\}.$ Assume for a contradiction that $S$ is countable, i.e., $S$ is the range of an infinite sequence:
$$S=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,\dots,f_n,\dots\}$$
Now define a function $g:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ by setting
$$g(n)=1-f_n(n).$$
Then $g\in S,$ so $g=f_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N.$ But $g(n)=1-f_n(n)\ne f_n(n),$ so $g\ne f_n,$ a contradiction. Therefore $S$ is uncountable.

In fact, $S$ has the same cardinality as the set of all real numbers. Let $\mathbb Q=\{r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots,r_n,\dots\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers. For $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\in\mathbb N$ define
$$\varphi_x(n)=\begin{cases}
1\text{ if }r_n\lt x,\\
0\text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}$$
Then the map $$x\mapsto\varphi_x$$ is an injection from $\mathbb R$ to $S,$ showing that $|\mathbb R|\le|S|.$ On the other hand, the map $$f\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{3^n}$$ is an injection from $S$ to $R,$ showing that $|S|\le|\mathbb R|.$ By the Cantor–Bernstein theorem, it follows that $|S|=|\mathbb R|.$

Comment: Please, can you show me how it's uncountable using Cantor's diagonal argument? Sorry for my ignorance and that's because I recently started studying (personally) the course! Then I'll accept your answer!

Comment: That's pretty much encouraging! You've really inspired me to continue in my studies! Thank you!

Comment: I really appreciate your patience and guidance! However, as a beginner in this new subject, I have some questions troubling my mind. Please, can you help me provide answers to the following questions? Your response would mean a lot to me!

Comment: **Q1:** Why is $\varphi_x$ injective? For me, I let $\varphi_x(n)=\varphi_y(n)\implies 1=1,$ whenever $r_n<x,y,$ but how do I proceed?

Comment: **Q2:** You used $f$ twice. So, I'm confused! Also, is the map $x\mapsto \varphi_x$ the same as $A:\Bbb{Q}\to\Bbb{N},x\mapsto A(x)= \varphi_x(n)$?

Comment: **Q3:** Is the map $f\mapsto \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{f(n)}{3^n}$ the same as $B:\{0,1\}\to\Bbb{R},f\mapsto B(f)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{f(n)}{3^n}$?

Comment: **Q4:** Please, how's $|\Bbb{R}|\leq |S|$ and  $|S|\leq |\Bbb{R}|$?

Comment: Kindly remember that I am being self-taught in this subject! So, I greatly depend on your reply to understand the whole proof, otherwise, I might end up cramming the solution, which will be very harmful to me. Thanks a lot for your help, I really do appreciate!

Comment: **Q1:** $\varphi_x$ is not injective; it is a map from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$ so it cannot be injective. However, the map $x\mapsto\varphi_x$ is injective: if $x,y\in\mathbb R,x\ne y,$ then $\varphi_x\ne\varphi_y.$ **Proof:** Without loss of generality, assume $x\lt y.$ Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R,$ we have $x\lt r_n\lt y$ for some $n\in\mathbb N.$ Then $\varphi_x(n)=0$ and $\varphi_y(n)=1,$ so $\varphi_x(n)\ne\varphi_y(n),$ so $\varphi_x\ne\varphi_y.$

Comment: **Q4:** $|\mathbb R|\le|S|$ because there is an injection from $|\mathbb R|$ to $|S|,$ and $|S|\le|\mathbb R|$ because there is an injection from $|S|$ to $|\mathbb R|.$ In general, for any sets $A$ and $B,$ the notation $|A|\le|B|$ means that there is an injection from $A$ to $B.$

Comment: **Q2:** I don't understand the question. The map $x\mapsto\varphi_x$ is not a map from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb N,$ it is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $S;$ it maps the real number $x\in\mathbb R$ to the function $\varphi_x\in S$ such that, for any $n\in\mathbb N,$ $\varphi(x)$ is either $1$ or $0$ depending on whether $r_n$ is less than $x$ or not.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! I wish I will one day become as great as you are! All questions were duly answered except **Q3**. I hope I got it right? Thanks once again for your time and guidance!